# How to split the data in the adapter

Tags: android, adapter

I have 10 items in an adapter,and I have two ListViews in an activity. Now I want to insert the first 5 items in one ListView and next 5 items in the second ListView ?

Answer (score 0):

Use two separate adapters with separate underlying data.